# Contingent values in ArcGIS Online - Need to update domain value in field based on another field value

Tags: field-calculator, arcgis-online, domains, arcade, field-mapping

I am trying to build a very simple calculation (or so I believe it should be) in Field Maps. I want the field, we'll call it "Calculations", to populate either "Compliant" or "Non-Compliant" in another field if the number the Crew enters is over/under/equal a certain amount. I could just remake the other Field for Compliance so it doesn't include Domain's/Lists but I have many and that would be a pain.

Here is what I have (but doesn't work since there is a list on the field I want the calculation to run):

```
if($feature.CALCULATIONS > 3) {return "Compliant"}
else{return "Non-Compliant"}
```

If I didn't use a domain/list, the calculation works fine. I've tried adding in the domain in the return field, as well, but Arcade doesn't seem to like that.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that, the values will returned ("Compliant", "Non-Compliant") is the code not label.
That is mean if code / label as follows:

- 1 / "Compliant"
- 2 / "Non-Complaint"

then in code return 1 or return 2

another thing in Field Maps designer make sure the field will updated not editable

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).